# Laravel 5: How to use redirect()->withInput() with forms that contain prepopulated values?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel 5. I'm trying to build a simple form to edit an existing record from the database, and I'm confused about how to use `withInput()` and `old()` in this case.

For example, consider the following routes and controllers:

```
<?php

// routes.php

use App\Book;

Route::get( '/book', [ 'as' => 'book.edit', function() {
    $book = Book::find(1);
    return view( 'book', [
        'title' => $book->title
    ] );
} ] );

Route::post( '/book', [ 'as' => 'book.update', function() {

    $validator = Validator::make( Request::all(), [
        // This validator will (almost) always fail. This is deliberate, to
        // illustrate the problem I'm describing.
        'title' => 'in:zzzzz|required'
    ] );

    if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        return redirect( route('book.edit') )
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors( $validator );
    }

    // TODO: save book

} ] );
```

Here's the corresponding template:

```
<!-- book.blade.php -->

<form action="{{ route('book.update') }}" method="post">

    <label>Book Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $title }}">

    @if ($errors->has('title'))
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
    @endif

    <button type="submit">Save</button>

    {{ csrf_field() }}

</form>
```

Now, consider the following user flow:

1. The user requests GET /book (we'll call this page load #1). The `book.edit` controller loads the book's title (which happens to be "50 Shades of Grey") from the database, and passes that string off to the view. The user sees the form with the value "50 Shades of Grey" prepopulated in the field. So far, so good.
2. The user modifies that title – say, to "A Tale of Two Cities" – and submits the form.
3. The `book.update` route processes this request, and finds it invalid. It redirects the user back to the `book.edit` route (we'll call this page load #2).
4. `book.edit` re-renders the same view, once again setting the value of `title` to "50 Shades of Grey" (which is incorrect).

**This is the part I'm trying to solve:** how can I display the title from the database on page load #1, but redisplay the user's input on page load #2?

Now, I understand *why* this code behaves this way. I just don't understand how I'm *supposed* to be doing it.

Possible solutions (and why I don't like them):

- In my template, I could use `value="{{ old('title') }}"` instead of `value="{{ $title }}"`. This will solve the problem on page load #2 – but it means that the `title` field will be *blank* on page load #1.
- I could add some logic to the view – something like: `{{ if $wasRedirected ? old('title') : $title }}` This just feels hackish and wrong – it doesn't seem like the sort of thing that should be in the view.
- I could add some logic to the `book.edit` request – something like `'title' => $wasRedirected ? Request::get('title') : $book->title`. This also feels hackish and wrong.

I'm probably just misunderstanding something, or missing something obvious. How is this aspect of edit forms *usually* handled in Laravel 5? There's gotta be a standard pattern, right?

Comment: It seems that one common solution is to install [the Forms & HTML component from Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html), which provides convenience methods that you can use in your view which automatically figure out what to display. I'm open to that option – but is there a way to do this in vanilla Laravel, without resorting to third-party add-ons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for the `old()` helper is:

```
function old($key = null, $default = null)
```

You can pass the value from the database as the default.

```
old('title', $book->title)
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I knew it had to be simple.

Comment: Cheers! On an added note, Laravel's "fetch by key" functions/methods/helpers usually have this signature.